# Change file execution path in Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, pycharm, jenkins-groovy

How can I change the execution `cpath` in Jenkins/Python configuration to exit the following error?

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

With `jenkins` I am calling the next command:

```
D:\Jenkins\workspace\Project>*C:\LegacyApp\Python\Python311*D:/Projects_Root/Tools/execution/DownloadSWFile.py
and i expect to have the next call. 
D:\Jenkins\workspace\Project> D:/Projects_Root/Tools/execution/DownloadSWFile.py
the difference is that i want to try to run it without the part in italicc....
```

What in my configuration might be wrong? The `venv` configuration? Or should I use system environment variables in windows settings?